# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Batch with 'id'=undefined) with Rails 7 Stimulus & nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hotwire-rails

My Rails 7 app uses the following models:

- `Batch` model, `has_many` tasks
- `Task` model, `belongs_to` a batch

Resources are nested as follows:

```
resources :batches do
  resources :tasks
end
```

The task model has a `completed` attribute which is a `boolean`.

I am following [this tutorial](https://My%20Rails%207%20app%20uses%20the%20following%20models:%20%20%20-%20%60Batch%60%20model,%20%60has_many%60%20tasks%20%20-%20%60Task%60%20model,%20%60belongs_to%60%20a%20batch%20%20Resources%20are%20nested%20as%20follows:%20%20%20%20%20%20resources%20:batches%20do%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resources%20:tasks%20%20%20%20%20end) — which works like a charm when starting a new Rails 7 app from scratch **without nested resources** — to mark tasks as completed when the corresponding checkbox is checked in the Tasks index view (and, conversely, to mark tasks as not completed when the corresponding checkbox is unchecked in the Tasks index view).

As hinted above, the main difference between the setup in the tutorial and my setup is that I use nested resources.

So, I have adapted the code from the tutorial as follows:

- `routes.rb` (I modified the `post "tasks/:id/toggle", to: "tasks#toggle"` route):

`post "batches/:batch_id/tasks/:id/toggle", to: "tasks#toggle"`

- `tasks_controller.js`(I added the `const batch_id ...` line):

```
    toggle(e) {
            const id = e.target.dataset.id
            const batch_id = e.target.dataset.batch_id
            const csrfToken = document.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").content
```

- `_task.html.erb` (I added the `batch_id: @batch.id` line):

```
    <%= form.check_box :completed,
                           data: {
                             batch_id: @batch.id,
                             id: task.id,
                             action: "tasks#toggle"
                           },
                           class: "mr-2 align-middle bg-gray-50 border-gray-300 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-blue-300 h-5 w-5 rounded checked:bg-green-500" %>
```

When I restart the server and try to mark a task as completed by checking a checkbox, I see the following error in Terminal:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Batch with 'id'=undefined):

app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:40:in `set_batch'
```

I also see the following error in the browser console (which does suggest that the `batch_id` is not sent properly, given that is shows up as `undefined`):

```
POST http://localhost:3000/batches/undefined/tasks/34/toggle 404 (Not Found)
```

Yet, when I inspect the checkbox element, it does seem that the `bach_id` showing up in the HTML:

```
<input data-batch-id="6" data-id="26" data-action="tasks#toggle" class="mr-2 align-middle bg-gray-50 border-gray-300 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-blue-300 h-5 w-5 rounded checked:bg-green-500" type="checkbox" value="1" name="task[completed]" id="task_completed">
```

I am hitting a wall, as I am not sure where to turn next to make this work: any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `const batch_id = e.target.dataset.batch_id` with `const batch_id = e.target.dataset.batchId` in tasks_controller.js solved the issue.